# APIConnectionError: Connection error. in langchain vector search

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-search, langchain, azure-openai, azure-ai-search

I am trying to implement a RAG solution using Azure OpenAI and Azure AI Search.

This is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
azure-core==1.29.6
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-identity==1.15.0
azure-keyvault-keys==4.8.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-search-documents==11.4.0
openai==1.8.0
langchain==0.1.1
fastapi==0.109.0
uvicorn==0.26.0
tiktoken==0.5.2
gunicorn==21.2.0
langchain-openai==0.0.2
```

I am trying to implement `RetrievalQA` using the following vector_store connection:

```
# Cognitive Search connection setting
index_name = os.environ["AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME"]
service_name = COGNOS_SERVICE
key = AZURE_SEARCH_ADMIN_KEY
vector_store_address = "https://{}.search.windows.net/".format(service_name)
vector_store_password = AZURE_SEARCH_ADMIN_KEY

# Define LLM
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    model="gpt-35-turbo",
    streaming=True,
    azure_deployment="chatgpt-gpt35-turbo",
    temperature=0.0,
)

embedding_model: str = "text-embedding-ada-002"
embeddings: OpenAIEmbeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(
    deployment=embedding_model, chunk_size=1
)
vector_store = AzureSearch(
    azure_search_endpoint=vector_store_address,
    azure_search_key=vector_store_password,
    index_name=index_name,
    embedding_function=embeddings.embed_query,
    # content_key="report_content"
)
```

When I run the following `vector_store` part I get the following error:

```
File d:\xxxx\.venv\lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py:919, in SyncAPIClient._request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
    909         return self._retry_request(
    910             options,
    911             cast_to,
   (...)
    915             response_headers=None,
    916         )
    918     log.debug("Raising connection error")
--> 919     raise APIConnectionError(request=request) from err
    921 log.debug(
    922     'HTTP Request: %s %s "%i %s"', request.method, request.url, response.status_code, response.reason_phrase
    923 )
    925 try:

APIConnectionError: Connection error.
```

I have made changes as per the new `langchain-community` imports.

The same code with older versions of `langchain` and the same connection settings seems to work.

What changes should I do to make the `vector_store` connection work?

Comment: In the vector_store you're assigning an index_name and running an embed_query function from an embeddings instance, do you have the index_name and embeddings defined anywhere? Such as embeddings: OpenAIEmbeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment=model, chunk_size=1)
index_name: str = "langchain-vector-demo"

Comment: yes. i have edited the code to reflect these